# How to get multiple selected file in grails?

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

I am trying to get **multiple selected files** and save into mysql

GSP CODE :

```
<input type="file" name="file_attachemnt" id="file_attachemnt" multiple/>
```

Controller Code For multiple file get

```
def all = request.getFileNames()

        all.each {name ->
           def file = request.getFile(name)
           def CommonsMultipartFile uploadedFile =file
           def fileName = uploadedFile.originalFilename
           println "file name "+fileName;
           def fileExtent=FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName);
        }
```

But in controller side only one file i get.. even if i selected e.g 3 files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try. Not sure but I don't think much has changed since the 1.3.x days and this works there.

```
request.getMultiFileMap().file_attachemnt.each {
    println it.originalFilename
}
```

Comment: on question.. how to get that file

Comment: The instance in that collection is a MultPartFile. You can find out more about it here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html Typically you will use the transferTo to write it to a file.

Comment: how to check ..file_attachement is null in this code.. because right now.. if i am not selecting a file then still its goes under this condtion..

Comment: According to the API documentation you can use it.isEmpty() to see if "the uploaded file is empty, that is, either no file has been chosen in the multipart form or the chosen file has no content."

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
params.list("file_attachemnt").each{
// your code here
}
```